# SD card shows up in dmesg, lsusb, and lswh, but not in lsblk or fdisk

Tags: files, mount, fdisk, sd-card, dmesg

Recently, my Android device has been unable to detect my SD card so I connected it to my PC (running Kubuntu) to figure out what's wrong. These are the results:

`dmesg` correctly detects the card reader and the attached mass storage device and shows an SCSI disk in `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, and `/dev/sdd`. I don't know why it shows up in all four. `stat` shows their sizes as 0. `mount` fails on all of them, saying no medium has been found.

`lsusb` detects the device correctly:

```
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 0dda:2026 Integrated Circuit Solution, Inc. USB2.0 Card Reader
```

`lswh -class disk` detects four disks, just like `dmesg`:

```
*-disk:0
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: IC1210        CF
       vendor: Generic
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 1.9C
       capabilities: removable
       configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/sda
  *-disk:1
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: IC1210        MS
       vendor: Generic
       physical id: 0.0.1
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.1
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       version: 1.9C
       capabilities: removable
       configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/sdb
  *-disk:2
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: IC1210    MMC/SD
       vendor: Generic
       physical id: 0.0.2
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.2
       logical name: /dev/sdc
       version: 1.9C
       capabilities: removable
       configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/sdc
  *-disk:3
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: IC1210        SM
       vendor: Generic
       physical id: 0.0.3
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.3
       logical name: /dev/sdd
       version: 1.9C
       capabilities: removable
       configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
     *-medium
          physical id: 0
          logical name: /dev/sdd
```

Neither `lsblk` nor `fdisk` give any output related to the SD card or to any `/dev/sd*` file.

Here's the full `dmesg` output:

```
    [Sep22 01:38] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
    [  +0.151453] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0dda, idProduct=2026, bcdDevice= 1.9c
    [  +0.000006] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [  +0.000003] usb 1-2: Product: USB2.0 Card Reader
    [  +0.000003] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Generic
    [  +0.000002] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 0000001
    [  +0.002622] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
    [  +0.000490] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
    [  +1.002628] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  IC1210        CF 1.9C PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
    [  +1.877520] scsi 1:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Generic  IC1210        MS 1.9C PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
    [  +1.877628] scsi 1:0:0:2: Direct-Access     Generic  IC1210    MMC/SD 1.9C PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
    [  +1.877198] scsi 1:0:0:3: Direct-Access     Generic  IC1210        SM 1.9C PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
    [  +0.000831] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0 
    [  +0.000566] sd 1:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
    [  +0.000448] sd 1:0:0:2: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
    [  +0.001047] sd 1:0:0:3: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
    [  +3.793444] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
    [  +0.010521] sd 1:0:0:2: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
    [  +0.002761] sd 1:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
    [  +0.002199] sd 1:0:0:3: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: So, two different devices cannot detect it? It could be dead, Jim.

Comment: Your memory card reader has four slots for different card types. Essentially, it treats the cards as removable "disks" while each slot is a separate "disk drive". Also, the `IC1210` might refer to [the chip used in the reader](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/6549/IC1210-F128LQ_Datasheet.pdf); if so, it's quite old and won't support the newer SDHC and SDXC card types. But if the card was previously readable by that reader and now isn't, then the card is probably dead.

Comment: I've never tried reading the card with this reader, so might be too old. Gonna look into that.